# dj-stripe does not switch to use live key on Live mode

Tags: django

I am creating a payment method using stripe.  Following tutorial, I was able to send test donation successfully.  When I switched to live mode and made a payment.  The log showed the payment was succeeded, with status 200 OK.  However, on the client side, django return an InvalidRequestError, No such token...  (see full message below).
Here is the error message:

```
InvalidRequestError at /membership/donate/500/
Request req_XjpOs2GYFxyP9K: No such token: tok_1FVm12LAhXPisFUbODE2xZhe; a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request.
```

According to the response body in stripe log, the missing token does exist:

```
{
  "id": "tok_1FVm12LAhXPisFUbODE2xZhe",
  "object": "token",
  "card": {
    "id": "card_1FVm12LAhXPisFUberAeLysv",
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    ...
    "metadata": {
    },
    "name": "myemail@yahoo.com",
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  "client_ip": "71.246.224.231",
  "created": 1571607164,
  "email": "myemail@yahoo.com",
  "livemode": true,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}
```

To complete the picture, here is the imported settings parameters:

```
STRIPE_LIVE_MODE        True
STRIPE_LIVE_PUBLIC_KEY  '********************'
STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY  '********************'
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY  '********************'
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY       '********************'
STRIPE_TEST_PUBLIC_KEY  '********************'
STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY  '********************'
```

The settings parameters show STRIPE_LIVE_MODE = True, and both public and secret keys are set to the live one with correct spelling.

The strange thing is, the value of local variable my_api_key in api_requester.py was test secret key, and not live secret key as it should be.

```
Variable       Value
headers        None
method         'post'
my_api_key     'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
params  
{'amount': 500,
 'currency': 'usd',
 'description': 'Donation',
 'source': 'tok_1FVmr9LAhXPisFUbRrmADugj'}
rbody             
(b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": "resource_missing",\n    "doc_url": "https://s'
 b'tripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",\n    "message": "No such to'
 b'ken: tok_1FVmr9LAhXPisFUbRrmADugj; a similar object exists in live mode, but'
 b' a test mode key was used to make this request.",\n    "param": "source",'
 b'\n    "type": "invalid_request_error"\n  }\n}\n')
rcode   400
```

What did I miss?  Any help would be very much appreciated!
pax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you've set `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` on your settings.py, try to remove it.

Take a look at [dj-stripe code](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/blob/master/djstripe/settings.py#L96), You'll see this:

```
# Default secret key
if hasattr(settings, "STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"):
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
else:
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = LIVE_API_KEY if STRIPE_LIVE_MODE else TEST_API_KEY
```

so if you define `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` on your setting, this key will be use to send stripe requests.